# Текст кнопки не меняется с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть кнопка. Мне надо, чтобы при ширине экрана меньше 340px, текст кнопки менялся. Я попытался написать скрипт, но он не работает. Вот [ссылка](https://codepen.io/maksimenkovvv/pen/abaQrXJ) на codepen. Код:

```js
if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 340) {
  function () {
    document.getElementById('button').innerHTML = 'Поменять текст'
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id='button'>Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Переведите ошибку. И вообще, функцию так-то вызывать надо, а не просто объявлять.

Comment: @ΝNL993, что вы имеете ввиду под "Переведите ошибку"?

Comment: @syrex это значит что вам нужно перевести ошибку на русский язык.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Даже если бы Ваш код не выдавал ошибки он все равно бы не работал так как написан не корректно с точки зрения языка `JS`. То что Вы поместили функцию в условие еще не значит что она выполнится. Нужно явно делать вызов функции и давать ей имя, есть случаи когда имя не обязательно, но это не тот случай. Хотя и не запрещено объявлять функцию везде где хочется лучше объявлять ее вне условий на глобальном уровне.*

Предложу сразу свое решение, которое будет отслеживать изменение размера окна и менять текст кнопки, мне кажется именно такую логику вы закладывали в свой код:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const mediaQuery = "screen and (max-width: 340px)"
const updateStyles = () => {
  const isMax340 = matchMedia(mediaQuery).matches   
  matchMedia(mediaQuery).addEventListener("change", updateStyles, 
   { 
     once: true 
     /* эта опция делает автоматическую отписку 
     от события после срабатывания — нет утечки памяти */
   })
  if (isMax340){
      document.getElementById('button').textContent = 'Поменять текст'
  } else {
      document.getElementById('button').textContent = 'Отправить'
  }
}
updateStyles(); // инициализация
```

```html
<div>
  <button id='button'>Отправить</button>
</div>
```

Решение основано на отслеживании изменений странице приводящих к активации различных `media query` в данном случае `js` позволяет нам отслеживать подобные изменения и проверять на то `активировался` или `деактивировался` конкретный запрос `"screen and (max-width: 340px)"` тут можно использовать любой валидный запрос, таким образом это решение максимально гибкое и универсальное. Надеюсь оно Вам подойдет.

Если Вам по какой-то причине не нужно такое сложное решение то я предлагаю посмотреть как переписать Ваше решение корректно:

```
function changeCaption(text) {
   document.getElementById('button').textContent = text
}

if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 340) {
   changeCaption('Поменять текст')
} else {
   changeCaption('Отправить')
}
```

Но стот заметить что такой код отработает 1 раз и не будет отслеживать изменений размера окна, например при развороте экрана и т.п.